# Allow certain users to see specific URLs in Symfony

Tags: security, symfony, access-control

I am currently struggling with an access_control problem :

I need every user to access every page on /user.

**But** I need **one** user (i.e. a particular **role**) to access **only** certain pages on /user (Let's say /user/profile and /user/register)

To clarify, I need a user that can access LESS pages than a regular user

I have been looking into access control but cannot find a way to implement this behavior apart from specifying it into every /user controller of my application.

Comment: Symfony Authorization can manage what you want. You may want to check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authorization.html this url.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put rules in your app/config.security.yml, like :

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/user/profile/$, role: YOUR_CUSTOM_ROLE }
```

?

Comment: Yes but YOUR_CUSTOM_ROLE also has the ROLE_USER.
Which makes the next rule, 
- { path: ^/user/$, role: ROLE_USER },
pass the YOUR_CUSTOM_ROLE users as well.